# Sort a multi-dimensional tensor using another tensor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, pytorch

I'm trying to sort `C` (see image) using `R` to get `Sorted_C`.

[image]

```py
c = torch.tensor([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]])
r = torch.tensor([[[0, 0, 0, 7.2, 0], [0, 25.4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 43.6, 0, 0], [61.8, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 80]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 98.2], [116.4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 134.6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 152.8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 169.2, 0]]])

# this is what I need
sorted_c = torch.tensor([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]])
```

How do I do this efficiently?

**correction**: expected ordering for `P6 to P10` should be: `P10 -> P6 -> P7 -> P8 -> P9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Minor note: it seems your example `r` doesn't quite match the values in your drawing. Also, it seems the result for `p6` through `p10` should be `p10 < p6 < p7 < p8 < p9`.*

---

When you hear "advanced indexing", you should think [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html). That is: the resulting tensor comes from the indexing of `c` column-wise with some kind of tensor we will extract from `r`.

First we can sum and sort `r` to get the indices of the columns:

```
>>> idx = r.sum(1).argsort(1)
tensor([[3, 1, 2, 0, 4],
        [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Then we can apply `torch.Tensor.gather` indexing `c` column-wise using the column indices contained in `idx` *i.e.* `dim=2` is the one varying based on values in `idx`. Explicitly the resulting tensor `out` is constructed such that:

```
out[i][j][k] = c[i][j][idx[i][j][k]]
```

Keep in mind both the index tensor (`idx`) and the value tensor (`c`) must have same dimension sizes except for the one that we're indexing on, here `dim=2`. Therefore, we need to expand `idx` such that it has the shape of `c`. We can do so with `None`-indexing and using [`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html) or [`expand_as`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand_as.html):

```
>>> idx[:,None].expand_as(c)
tensor([[[3, 1, 2, 0, 4],
         [3, 1, 2, 0, 4],
         [3, 1, 2, 0, 4],
         [3, 1, 2, 0, 4]],

        [[4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
         [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
         [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
         [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]]])
```

Notice the duplicated values row-wise (fiy: they're not copies, `expand` is makes a view not a copy!)

Finally, we can gather the values in `c` to get the desired result:

```
>>> c.gather(2, idx[:,None].expand_as(c))
tensor([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]])
```

Comment: Thank you as always, Ivan. Your help (solution along with details) is much appreciated!